# Placement of adverb in independent clause preceded by dependent clause

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis

Which sentence is correct?

1. To simplify the notation, we will denote henceforth the distance by d.
2. To simplify the notation, henceforth we will denote the distance by d.

Comment: They are both grammatical, as is "*...we will henceforth denote...*. And proofreading is off-topic here, in general.

Comment: It seems to me that if *. …we will denote henceforth the distance by d* were acceptable, that could only be in honour of an archaic form.